# ANDROID: Navigation drawer menuItem Shared Element transition

Tags: android, android-animation, shared-element-transition

I am trying to implement **Shared Element transition** for navigation drawer menu

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_studentprofile"
        android:icon="@drawable/studentprofile"
        android:title="@string/student_profile"
        />
```

I have another activity with an `ImageView` and `TextView`,

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/studentprofile"
    android:id="@+id/imageview_studentprofile" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/student_profile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textview_studentprofile"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

But for shared element transition i have to pass the View of the element,
I am not able to convert the menuItem to `View`

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_studentprofile) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_classeshistory) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_studentattendance) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_datetracking) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I want to convert the `MenuItems` to `view` then use that view in Shared Element transition

My first Activity

[image]

My second Activity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When an item is clicked, you can use `item.getActionView();` to get the menuitem view, but that works only if you added a custom view on your drawer items.

So create a dummy custom view for navigation drawer items:`layout name:dummy_drawer_item` and set `android:transitionName="@string/transition_string"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    <!-- Add this line -->
    android:transitionName="@string/transition_string">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in menu/drawer_items, add your custom view `app:actionLayout="@layout/dummy_drawer_item"` foreach item. ex:

```
 <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Import"
            <!-- Add this line -->
            app:actionLayout="@layout/dummy_drawer_item"/>
        ...
```

Finally, when item is clicked:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

...
 //Get the view of menuitem
  View v = item.getActionView();
//Call your other activity 
 // Get the transition name from the string
    String transitionName = getString(R.string.transition_string);

    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, view, transitionName);

    //Start the Intent
    ActivityCompat.startActivity(this, new Intent(this, YourOtherActivity.class),  options.toBundle());

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Im using fragment transaction...is it possible to do shared element transition while doing fragment transaction using navigation drawer...